# The graph has 10 vertices and 47 edges.

Tags: graph-theory

The graph has $10$ vertices and $47$ edges.

Does such a graph actually exist?

Comment: You should specify whether or not you are allowing loops or multiple edges between two vertices.

Comment: Moreso, you may want to specify if the graph is directed or not.

Answer (score 2):

No a complete graph with10 vertices has $10\times{}9/2=45$ edges.